CSS and JavaScript not applying correctly in a specific component when fetching data from an external API
I'm facing an issue in my Angular application where CSS and JavaScript don't apply correctly to a carousel component when fetching data from an external API. The data retrieval process takes a significant amount of time, and as a result, the carousel's styles are not applied properly when the component first loads.
courses.component.html :
<section class="course-section bg-grey padding">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-heading mb-40 text-center">
      <h2>Populer Courses</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and industry.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="course-carousel" class="course-carousel owl-carousel">
      <div class="course-item" *ngFor="let course of courses | slice:0:12">
        <div class="course-thumb">
          <img src="assets/img/course-1.jpg" alt="course">
          <a class="enroll-btn" href="#">Book Now <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
          <div class="thumb-details">
            <img src="assets/img/team-1.jpg" alt="img">
            <div class="thumb-content">
              <h4>Devid Cameroon</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="course-details">
          <h3><a href="#">{{course.name}}</a></h3>
          <p>{{course.description}}</p>
          <div class="course-footer">
            <span><i class="fa fa-group"></i>763</span>
            <span><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>205</span>
            <span class="price">$499</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /#item-1 -->

    </div>
  </div>
</section><!-- /#Course-Section -->

typescript file :
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoursesService } from '../services/courses.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.scss']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {


  courses: any[] = [];
  constructor(private coursesService: CoursesService) { }
  getCourses() {

    this.coursesService.showAllcourses().subscribe(courses => {

      console.log("this courses length:", courses.length);
      this.courses = courses;
      console.log("new courses table", this.courses);

    });

  }


  loadScripts() {

    // This array contains all the files/CDNs
    const dynamicScripts = [

      "../../assets/js/vendor/owl.carousel.min.js",

      //Load all your script files here'
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
      const node = document.createElement('script');
      node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.async = false;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
    //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.

    this.getCourses();

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //Called after ngAfterContentInit when the component's view has been initialized. Applies to components only.
    //Add 'implements AfterViewInit' to the class.
    this.loadScripts();
  }

}

angular.json :
 "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets/"],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/css-animation.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/owl.carousel.css",
              "src/assets/css/venobox/venobox.css",
              "src/assets/css/nivo-slider.css",
              "src/assets/css/elegant-font-icons.css",
              "src/assets/css/elegant-line-icons.css",
              "src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/slicknav.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/themify-icons.css",
              "src/assets/css/responsive.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js",

              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery.slicknav.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery.waypoints.v2.0.3.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery.counterup.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery.isotope.v3.0.2.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/owl.carousel.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js",

              "src/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js",

              "src/assets/js/vendor/smooth-scroll.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/tether.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/venobox.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/vendor/wow.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/main.js"
            ]
          },

index.html :
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularProject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="WowThemez">
  <title>Unimax || Education Html Template</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
  <app-root></app-root>

</body>

</html>

Here's the situation:
Initial Load: The component takes a long time to fetch data from the API, causing the CSS for the carousel to not apply correctly.
Page Reload: When I reload the page, the carousel works perfectly, with the data loading from the cache and the CSS applying as it should.
I've attached screenshots below to show the difference in behavior between the initial load and after reloading the page.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue, and can you suggest any solutions to ensure that the CSS and JavaScript for the carousel are applied correctly even during the first load


I've tried loading the script in the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook, but the CSS for the carousel doesn't load correctly on the first attempt. However, when I reload the page, everything works as expected (the data loads from the cache, and there's no delay).

Please see [ask]. You're expected to show some code in your question.

Where are the screenshots am I the one who can't see them?

Try converting the js files to typescript files and add the functions in the component  normally.
